# How to prevent Thunderbird from rewriting URLs to hyperlinks when composing html emails?

Tags: html, email, thunderbird

I'm using Thunderbird 52.5.2 on Windows 7.

When I compose the html emails and send, Thunderbird will convert the email addresses and the http:// urls I wrote to clickable hyperlinks when sending the email out. I don't want Thunderbird to do that for me and I would do that manually when I need by insert->links.

How to prevent Thunderbird from automatically rewriting URLs to hyperlinks when I compose and send the html emails ?

For example, I would like to compose a html email like this:

[Email content I composed (I'm not able to embed img now, please click to view)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7mJC.png)

Thunderbird will rewrite the email address and http url as below (source code view)

```
<html>
  <head>

    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=en-US">
  </head>
  <body text="#000000" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <b>H</b><i>ELLO</i><br>
    This is an email address <a class="moz-txt-link-abbreviated" href="mailto:dummy@example.com">dummy@example.com</a><br>
    This is a http url <a class="moz-txt-link-freetext" href="http://www.example.com/dummy.html">http://www.example.com/dummy.html</a><br>
    <br>
  </body>
</html>
```

But I want Thunderbird keep what I wrote as below (source code view):

```
<html>
  <head>

    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=en-US">
  </head>
  <body text="#000000" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <b>H</b><i>ELLO</i><br>
    This is an email address dummy@example.com<br>
    This is a http url http://www.example.com/dummy.html<br>
    <br>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop Thunderbird from automatically hyperlinking on send](https://superuser.com/q/455270/114185) on [SU].

Comment: Sorry, I searched before I post this question. Maybe I have wrong key words to search. Well, this hyperlink problem seems unresolvable. :(

Answer (score 3):

Inspired from previous answer. I found another trick that DO make Thunderbird render my email correctly which has no clickable links.

When I compose a html email and edit to an email address, I have to manually use insert-->html it as below:

`dummy<span>@</span>example.com`

and below is for html urls:

`http<span>:</span>//www.example.com/dummy.html`

Then I got a perfect result.

Answer (score 1):

I have wanted the same feature you requested, but the closest I have been able to get it is using the following work-around.

1) After I create the email, instead of immediately sending, I use the "send later" feature which places the email into the Outbox folder. See https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/send-later-button/?src=search?src=search
At this point the email if formatted with the HTML codes for anchor text and hyperlinks as the OP indicated.

2) Then I use the "Edit Full Source" feature of "Header Tools Lite" Add-On to remove the unwanted HTML code. See https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/header-tools-lite/?src=search?src=search

BTW, the other work-arounds provided by others above, leave HTML code in the email. Though the hyperlink within the email may not function, the anchor text still remains formatted as a link. This is because of the lingering HTML codes remaining in the email.

Answer (score 0):

One trick I found is to enclose the url in `<a>`..`</a>` tags.
This may seem silly, but it will prevent linkification from taking place, and without a `href` attribute, there will be no other interaction.

```html
This is an email address <a>dummy@example.com</a><br>
```

Comment: But it still a link. I want it untouched as what I wrote. Anyway, thanks.